Rollup report error when build our library with solana/web3
I have a library using solana/web3.js@1.95.0 which build with rollup.
And I encounter an error:
RollupError: node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js (6:9): "serialize"  is not exported by "node_modules/borsh/lib/index.js", imported by  "node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js".
I try to solve it, but can find little information about this.

I'm not sure if this helps, but this rollup build for spl-stake-pool seems to work with the newest web3.js: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/stake-pool/js/rollup.config.mjs
